# Decoding meta values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding meta tag in a placeholder via server side logic

```
    var meta = new HtmlMeta();
    meta.Attributes.Add("property", "content");
    meta.Content = "Jame's item";
    return meta;
```

After that I am adding that to a placeholder to render in a page. The issue is that the value of that property becomes encoded when I see them in View source i.e it is rendered as

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Jame&#39;sitem" />
```

I am not able to figure out how and from where this encoding is being done? Is it possible to render the value as "Jame's item"

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid HtmlMeta like many [other controls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sfaust/archive/2008/09/02/which-asp-net-controls-automatically-encodes.aspx) automatically encodes content and values.
You could use Literal, building your own tag from scratch.